# Spring Batch: Is it possible to write to flat file till a threshold has reached and than write to a new one?

Tags: spring-batch

I would like to write to a flat file till a some threshold reached, and once reached - create a new file and write to it, it is possible with Spring Batch ?

I found an old question with an answer saying it is not possible but not sure it is updated:

[Spring Batch: Can i write to multiple files based on Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309967/spring-batch-can-i-write-to-multiple-files-based-on-size)

Another option is to use the chunk-size and handle the file creation manually but it will be better to use a Spring Batch capability if such exist.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`MultiResourceItemWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemWriter.html) is what you are looking for. The threshold you are describing is actually the `ItemCountLimitPerResource` parameter.